# How do I shift letters down in a loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a loop which only returns letters. In my code, I get symbols that I don't want. How do I fix my loop so that when my integer is +3, it only gives me letters?

```
public static String caesarDecrypt(String encoded, int shift){
    String decrypted = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++) {
        char t = encoded.charAt(i);

        if ((t <= 'a') && (t >= 'z')) {
            t -= shift;
        }

        if (t > 'z') {
            t += 26;
        } else if ((t >= 'A') && (t <= 'Z')) {
            t -= shift;

            if (t > 'Z') 
                t += 26;
        } else {

        }

        decrypted = decrypted + t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give an example of input and output please.

Comment: I had to double-check that the format edit didn't change any logic, and it doesn't look like it did.  That said...what's going on with the empty `else` statement, and what do you expect to accomplish with the `+= 26` bits strewn about?  Also, you may have one too many curly braces floating about.

Comment: @Makoto what do you mean? Just changed the indentation..

Comment: For example if i have the letter 'a' I want to convert it to 'x' which is three spaces behind it. Instead I'm getting characters. I understand it has to do with the ASCII values but I can't seem to find away around it. The +=26 are supposed to help the loop go back to the letters. For example at 'z' i want the loop to jump back to 'a'.

Comment: @YassinHajaj:  I'm aware of that, but then I noticed more of those...oddities.  Just double-checking the work that was done is all.

Comment: @AlexCabo: += 26 is probably *not* going to do what you want it to do, as you're going to be adding 26 to a `char` which would produce another `char` value which is 26 characters away from where you started...it definitely wouldn't wrap around.

Comment: @Makoto How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting the shift value from the letters. Therefore, the new letter can never be `> 'z'`. You should check if the it is `< 'a'` (or `'A'`, respectively).

```
StringBuilder decrypted = new StringBuilder(encoded.length());
for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++)
{
    char t = encoded.charAt(i);
    if ((t >= 'a') && (t <= 'z'))
    {
        t -= shift;
        while (t < 'a')
        {
            t += 26;
        }
    }
    else if ((t >= 'A') && (t <= 'Z'))
    {
        t -= shift;
        while (t < 'A')
        {
            t += 26;
        }
    }

    decrypted.append(t);
}
return decrypted.toString();
```

Also, you shouldn't be using String concatenation to generate the result. Learn about `StringBuilder` instead.

***EDIT***: To make sure the new letter is in the range `'a' .. 'z'` for an arbitrary (positive) shift, you should use `while` instead of `if`.

Comment: This still gave me the same problems

Comment: It just returned "333333333333"

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving you exact code. But I can help you in logic:

1. Check whether you are reaching end points (**a, A, z, Z**) due to the shift.
2. If you exceed the end points either way, then compute the **distance** between end    points and shifted ***t***. Add/subtract/modulus (based on the end point) this **distance** to the other endpoint to get the exact letter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (Warning, untested)

```
public static String caesarDecrypt(String encoded, int shift) {
    String decrypted = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++) {
        char t = encoded.charAt(i).ToUpper();

        decrypted = decrypted + decode(t, shift);
    }
}


// call with uppercase ASCII letters, and a positive shift
function decode(char n, int shift)
{
   if ((n < 'A') || (n > 'Z')) return ('-');

   var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   var s = str.charAt(((n - 'A') + shift)%26);
   return(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are naming your method `caesarDecrypt` (I assume you mean *encrypt*), I think you want a shift in the alphabet including wrapping around.

This code will do that for you:

```
public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(caesarShift("This is a Fizzy test.", 5));
        System.out.println(caesarShift("Ymnx nx f Kneed yjxy.", -5));
    }

    public static String caesarShift(String input, int shift) {
        // making sure that shift is positive so that modulo works correctly
        while (shift < 0)
            shift += 26;

        int l = input.length();
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            char newLetter = c;

            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') { // lowercase
                newLetter = (char) ((c - 'a' + shift) % 26 + 'a'); // shift, wrap it and convert it back to char
            } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') { // uppercase
                newLetter = (char) ((c - 'A' + shift) % 26 + 'A'); // shift, wrap it and convert it back to char
            }

            output.append(newLetter);
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

This will handle **lowercase and uppercase** letters. Everything else will be left as it is (like spaces, punctuations, etc).

Please take some time to look at this code to understand how it works. I have put some comments to make it clearer. From your code I think you were a bit confused, so it is important that you understand this code very well. If you have questions, feel free to ask them.

---

This code

```
String start = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String encrypted = caesarShift(start, 3);
String decrypted = caesarShift(encrypted, -3);
System.out.println("Start     : " + start);
System.out.println("Encrypted : " + encrypted);
System.out.println("Decrypted : " + decrypted);
```

will give this result

```
Start     : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Encrypted : defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc
Decrypted : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: It won't let me append my output for some reason

Comment: Because my output is a string named so it won't let me append my characters, how do I get around that?

Comment: @AlexCabo You should use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` to construct strings like that (better performance). If that is not possible, instead of `StringBuffer#append()` you can still use concatenation of strings like you did: `yourString += newLetter;`.

Comment: thank you, but is there a reason instead of 'z' I'm getting back 't'? It's the only problem I have left

Comment: I need to know your call. What is the input string, what is the shift value?

Comment: Also my input is the entire alphabet, as I want to test this out for every letter. It works fine but I get T twice, in its place and instead of z

Comment: That is strange, when I call `System.out.println(caesarShift("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 3));`, I get `defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc` as a result. Maybe something Locale specific?

Comment: Must be because I keep getting a T

Comment: Have you copy pasted that string from somewhere or wrote it yourself? Maybe, there is also something with unicode going on. Try writing the alphabet yourself.

Comment: Strange it worked now. But also, when I tried to make a method that work backwards, that's to say given the letter 'a' I want an output 3 characters behind it, all characters work except for a, b and c which give me symbols. I thought the modulus would help me get around that but it doesn't?

Comment: My code also allows for negativ shifts (for example, use -3 as shift value to decrypt something that was encrypted with +3). Modulus on negativ numbers is not very intuitive and defined different for different programming languages.

Comment: That works but it still gives me weird symbols in place of a, b, and c

Comment: Can you copy paste your specific call/calls?

Comment: I added some text at the end of my answer that shows the results when you convert the full alphabet with 3 and then decrypt it again with -3.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply I was away but here is my call : System.out.println(caesarEncrypt("ABC", -3))

Comment: and here is my output: >?@

Comment: My output for your call is `XYZ`. Does it do the same thing for lowercase `abc`?

Comment: Yes except its a different set of symbols.

Comment: Could I have been doing it right this whole time and my PC was simply messing something up for me? I often have to close Dr Java and restart it (although I did it many times for this method)

Comment: The PC never messes up, it is always doing what you are telling him to do. Most of the times you think that you are telling him something but it's something else though. ;) Did you include the while loop I inserted in the beginning of my method? It is very important for negativ shifts.

Comment: I didn't see your while loop! But I was trying to do another method that's the exact opposite of this one instead of simply replacing the shift